# eGit merge conflict - wrong content in comparison for staged file

Tags: eclipse, merge, conflict, egit, mergetool

We've been using git and eGit in eclipse (Helios and Juno - this issue is same in both) fairly successfully up until a merge we tried this morning.

We have a branch **G_Claims** (which I've checked is synchronised between local and remote), commit latest set of changes, push them up and then want to merge some recent work on **master** into it, so that our changes do not affect **master** until we have finished and merge them in.

So.
o) Latest changes
o) Commit (which pushes up to remote **G_Claims**
o) Merge -> **remote/master**

there are conflicts.
click on first marked file (marked as staged - black and white asterisk) to perform Team -> MergeTool
compare with HEAD or compare with Working file (doesnt matter in this case ,both have same result)

it shows the current file on the left hand page, and on the right hand side it shows a file which is labelled with the latest commit on **remote/master** (say 'My change' abd76f...) but shows the content of a completely different version.

Now, if we click on a different file, that is marked for needing conflict resolution (red diamond), then the comparison correctly shows the **remote/master** ('My change' abd76f...) version file in the right hand panel.

Is this simply a visual bug when you use MergeTool to 'resolve' a staged file

(since the merge was automatic for this file)

Is clicking MergeTool to expect to 'see' the merge changes wrong? In which case We need just remember to use compare head for (partially) staged files after merge, and only use MergeTool for conflicted ones?

It appears to be showing the right information, but perhaps it is just the *label* of the right hand panel that is wrong - that it should be showing the (previous??) version of the file before the merge but labelleing it something else - NOT 'My Change' abd76f... which it clearly isnt...